# Determine the type of the non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to determine whether the non linear ODE has constant coefficients or not ? 
Does "constant coefficients" mean that the coefficients do not depend on x ?

For example  :

The following ODE
$$yy'y''+y'+y=0$$
is non linear ODE with constant coefficients since the coefficients do not depend on x (although the coefficient of y'' is y y' , we check dependence of the coefficient on x only? )

while the following ODE is non linear ODE with variable coefficients since some of them depend on x ?
$$y'y''+4xy'+2x^3y=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remeber that a linear ODE is a diferential equation such that if $\{ \varphi_1,...,\varphi_k\}$ is a set of solutions of that ODE, then $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k a_j\varphi_j$, where each $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$, is also a solution; that is, a linear combination of solutions is also a solution.

Now, let us consider for example the following ordinary diferential equations: 
\begin{equation}
4y´´-8y=x^2,\\
(x^2+1)y''-8xy=x^2.
\end{equation}
Note that the only difference is that in the first equation the coeficients are CONSTANTs (in this case real numbers) and in the second equation the coeficients are non-constant functios. The first one is a caled an ODE with constant coeficients and the second one is called an ODE with non-constant coeficients.

What you said is correct, in your examples the first equation is an ODE with constant coeficients (they don't depend on $x$).

Comment: So we determine constant/variable coefficients for Non linear ODE in the same way as we determine it for Linear ODE ! .. Thanks that 's help ..

Comment: You're welcome!